# Any way for openssl to generate private key with 400 (-r--------) permissions from the start?

Tags: openssl, file-permissions, umask

I use `openssl` to generate private keys and CSRs in a script.  The script needs to generate the key first, then call `chmod 400 whatever.key` to change the permissions of the private key to something more secure.

Is there any way to eliminate the second step and have `openssl` create the file with appropriate permissions from the start?  It would seem cleaner to me to not have the private key readable by other processes, even for a millisecond.

Can you use `umask` in a script to do something like this or is there another way?

Comment: Looks like my  question is answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196802/remove-passphrase-from-private-key-and-set-specific-file-mode
But that's a different site so I can't flag as duplicate.

Comment: according to tradition, this still count as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

I found an [answer to my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196804/7008) over at unix.stackexchange.com.

The idea is to use umask and run the commands in round brackets to execute it in a subshell, so umask doesn't affect the rest of the script.

> ```
> ( umask 077; openssl rsa -in secure.key -out insecure.key )
> ```

Comment: Note: that will probably result in a key file with permission of 600 or 700; to get 400 I think the umask should be 0377.  Not that there is really any significant difference between them in this particular case.